# MATLAB:how can I use fprintf or sprintf to print matrix and vectors with strings togheter?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, vector, printf

I'm at the beginning with the MATLAB software ,and I have two questions:

1) If I want to print a matrix, preceeded by a string, using the     fprintf   command, how can I do?
For example, to print a matrix alone, I use

```
fprintf([repmat('%d\t', 1, size(r, 2)) '\n'], r');
```

But how can I print a string followed by the matrix, all togheter in fprintf, without usind the disp   function ?
For example, if I want to print:

```
>>The matrix you inserted is [1 3; 4 6]
```

2) How can I do the same thing with vectors (I know it's only a particular case of matrix) ?
I actually use, for example:

```
>>vectorname=[1 5 2];
>>strtrim(sprintf('%d  ', vectorname));
```

And it's ok for the only numbers of the vector, but If I insert a string in spintf the result is:

```
 >>vectorname=[1 5 2];
 >>strtrim(sprintf('Your vector is:  %d  ', vectorname))

 >>Your vector is 1 Your vector is 5 Your vector is 2
```

How can I inglobe the numbers, one ofter the other, with only one command (sprintf, fprintf, ecc.)??

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases you can use [`mat2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html).

#### First case:

```
input_mat = [1 3; 4 6];
sprintf(['The matrix you inserted is ' mat2str(input_mat)])
```

```
ans =

The matrix you inserted is [1 3;4 6]
```

#### Second case:

```
vectorname=[1 5 2];
sprintf(['Your vector is: ', mat2str(vectorname)])
```

```
ans =

Your vector is: [1 5 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one thing: is it possible to make the matrix (like a 3x3 matrix look in the classic form, with columns and rows?

Comment: @user5512412 - it probably is possible somehow, but that wasn't your original question - and adding more tasks to your question after it was answered is frowned upon on SO. You might want to ask that as a separate question since it may require more creativity. Also, consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: For future readers: [here's the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482741/matlab-fprintf-sprintf-to-print-string-matrix/33484032#33484032) to the 1st comment above.